# How to generate a raster showing min/max values from a stack of rasters? QGIS and Python

Tags: qgis, python, raster

I have a stack of rasters (NDVI values over a year) and I want to generate a single raster showing the maximum difference between the layers.

So the result should be a single raster showing the difference between maximum value and minimum value for each point across the landscape. How can I do this in QGIS or Python?

Answer (score 3):

If you have GRASS configured with QGIS you can use `r.series` to do this.

Run `r.series` from the processing toolbox.

Select your raster layers.

Choose `range`, and run.

[image]

That gives me a new raster in the layer list which overlays my 5 source rasters. If I query these in QGIS I can see the pixel values in my 5 layers and the range pixel value.

[image]

In this case `r1` and `r5` are the raster with the smallest and biggest values, and `Aggregate` is exactly the difference between them - 5.13 - 1.33

Answer (score 1):

You can use `python` `gdal` bindings and `numpy` to do this.

Here I present a general example:

```
from osgeo.gdalconst import *
from osgeo import gdal
import numpy as np
import os

arrs = []

for fn in os.listdir(r"folder with rasters"):
   ds = gdal.Open(r"folder with rasters/{}".format(fn))
   arr = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
   arrs.append(arr)
   del ds

stack = np.stack(arrs)
new_arr = stack.max(axis=0) - stack.min(axis=0)

driver = ds.GetDriver()
dsOut = driver.Create('diff_raster.tif', new_arr.shape[1], new_arr.shape[0], 1, GDT_Float64)
outBand = dsOut.GetRasterBand(1)
outBand.WriteArray(new_arr, 0, 0)

outBand.FlushCache()
outBand.SetNoDataValue(-9999)

dsOut.SetGeoTransform(ds.GetGeoTransform())
dsOut.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())

del ds, dsOut, outBand
```

You can  change the new raster Data Type depending on what you need. Just look for an appropiate `gdalconst` here: http://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdalconst-module.html/#Variables

Comment: I get an error when I try the code: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user1/Documents/GIS DATA/SENTINEL2/2017_NDVI_UNCLIPPED/PythonStack/stack.py", line 10, in <module>
    arr = np.array(ds.GetRasterBand(1).ReadAsArray())
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'

Comment: It is because `gdal` did not open the raster. Are you sure you put the right path folder? Usually happens when paths are wrong.

Comment: I added for fn in os.listdir('./clipped_source'):
   print (fn)
   and it lists the name of the first file OK but then gives the same "AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetRasterBand'"

Comment: @SteveResearch Yeah, my bad. I just updated the code. `fn` was only the name so gdal could not find that "path". Try now and let me know if it works